# how to calculate number of nodes?

Tags: networking

I'm wondering how to calculate number of nodes in CIDR network?
for example if the CIDR network is 11.13.0.0/16 How many nodes can be accommodated in this CIDR network? 
Any help would be appreciatet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'll have a *broadcast* address, so that's one address removed. You'll also typically have a router/default gateway, so that's often one more address removed. So that leaves `2^(32-16)-2==65534` IP addresses free for other use. If you want to subnet that further, you'll lose one more IP per subnet, since each subnet will have its own broadcast range.

Comment: 655334 Is that total number of all nodes/hosts in the network?

Answer (score 1):

In general terms thats `2^(32-bits_set_in_mask)` addresses. As sarnold pointed out some of those can't be used for nodes.